# How to determine if the path to the address is a dirt or paved road?

Tags: here-api

Problem: I want to tell if the access road to an US address includes dirt or paved road(like if it is in a remote area without proper road). If it is a dirty road we charge more to the customer for delivery.

In technical terms - The input is going to be a house address and I need to find out if the way to it involves dirt road.

I am ok with making multiple calls to get the complete information. What steps do I need to take?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which HERE API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will probably need two steps:

1. Use [HERE Routing API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html) to calculate the route between the two locations. It will return the path information.
2. Get the road attribute from one of the following content sources, such as [Map Attribute API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/content-map-attributes/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html), [Road Physical Attributes in HERE Map Content](https://developer.here.com/documentation/here-map-content/dev_guide/topics-attributes/physical-attributes.html).